# Node.js - difference between creating a form for a request versus getting it from request.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, request, form-data

Today I was adding the ability to upload a photo to Facebook to a site I'm working on. The site is built in Express node.js, and I'm using the request npm module to upload.

I kept getting the error message: "(#324) Requires upload file". I thought this had to do with the photo file I was trying to upload, so I'd try different variations of converting it to base64, changing headers, manually creating POST requests, etc.

I ended up trying the entire code of one response, and to my surprise, it worked, even though the image data was just from `fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)`, which I'd tried many times before.

I found out that the difference was how I was adding the form-data to my request. Originally, I defined it inline:

```
request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + req.user.facebook.token,
        method: "POST",
        form: {
            source: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
            message: req.body.message
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        if(bodyJSON.error) {
            console.log(bodyJSON.error.message);
        }
    });
```

This kept giving me the error I mentioned previously. The code I found looks a bit different.

```
serverRequest = request.post('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + req.user.facebook.token, function(err, res, body) {
    var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
    if(bodyJSON.error) {
            console.log(bodyJSON.error.message);
    }
});

form = serverRequest.form()
// append a normal literal text field ...
form.append('message', req.body.message);

// append a file field by streaming a file from disk ...
form.append('source', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path));
```

This works. So I decided to compare the two different form objects. They're quite big, so I put them on Pastebin. first one can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/6JecSkJ1) and the second [here](http://pastebin.com/eE6E36ae). There are massive differences.

Now I'm wondering two things:

1. Why are two different form-datas created? What is the difference between the two methods of creating/appending to them?
2. How does appending to the form from the request in method 1 work? When does the post request actually happen? I'd assume it does on request.post(..), but then I can append stuff to the form-data before it gets posted.

**Edit: Question Answered Below**
The question is answered by mscdex. Here is the code I'm now using for the request, in case anyone else needs it.

```
request.post(
    {
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, 
        formData: {
            message: message,
            source: fs.createReadStream(imageFile.path) 
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        if(bodyJSON.error) {
            console.log(bodyJSON.error.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`request` documentation](https://github.com/request/request#forms) explains the difference. The first form is for submitting requests of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while the second is for submitting requests of type `multipart/form-data`.

(Binary) Files typically cannot be submitted with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests, so `multipart/form-data` is usually used instead (although some web services may allow you to submit a single file via a `PUT` request where the content of the request is the raw file contents).

The HTTP request isn't sent immediately at the time of `request()` because it's asynchronous and it takes time to do a DNS lookup, set up a TCP connection used to make the HTTP request, etc. So during that time you *could* append more fields to the form (assuming `request` does not artificially stop you from doing so after say the next tick of the event loop), but it's best to add them all at once just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've read through the documentation but somehow missed the headings on the form parts. I'll change my code to pass in the `multipart/form-data` instead of adding it in after. Thanks also for explaining the process behind the HTTP request, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I've added the new, just-to-be-safe code to the original answer. I checked, and it works.